# Beginner Oracle 11g SQL - Create Pivot Table from joining multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table

I have multiple tables, each with FK relationships that connect them to one another.  I need to create a pivot table using details out of some of the tables.

```
Region Table
Region_ID|Region_Description

State Table
State_ID|State_Description|Region_ID_FK

Order Table
Order_ID|Order_Date|State_ID_FK

Category Table
Category_ID|Category|Description|Order_ID_FK
```

I am joining all the tables using a natural join, based on the FKs.

I need to determine how many orders are in each category for each region.

The resulting table should look like this:

```
 Category|Region1|Region2|Region3|Total
 Sporting    1       0      3      4
 ETC         0       2      1      3
```

Comment: Great.,  What have you tried?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Sorry - Had issues with formatting:

    SELECT Category, COUNT(DECODE(Region_Description, 'Region1','Region1')) Region1, COUNT(DECODE(Region_Description, 'Region2','Region2')) Region2, COUNT(DECODE(Region_Description, 'Region3','Region3')) Region3
    FROM Category JOIN Orders USING (Order_ID_FK) JOIN State
    USING (State_ID_FK) JOIN Region USING (Region_ID_FK)
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (Category, ())
    ORDER BY Category;

I keep getting zero rows...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Category,
       COUNT( CASE r.Region_ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Region1,
       COUNT( CASE r.Region_ID WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Region2,
       COUNT( CASE r.Region_ID WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Region3,
       COUNT( CASE r.Region_ID WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Region4 
FROM   REGION r
       INNER JOIN
       STATE s
       ON (r.Region_ID = s.Region_ID_FK)
       INNER JOIN
       ORDER o
       ON (s.State_ID = o.State_ID_FK)
       INNER JOIN
       CATEGORY c
       ON (o.Order_ID = c.Order_ID_FK)
GROUP BY c.Category
```